# How to get a list of to-be-added files that don't have svn:mime-type property set?

Tags: svn, version-control, shell

I am trying to perform a *big* checkin of a lot of semi-automatically generated files, and they should all have `svn:mime-type` properties.  I've set a lot using `find`, but how do I now find all those remaining files that are to be added and which haven't had a MIME type assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Seth's basic idea, I did

```
for x do
  mt=$(svn pg svn:mime-type $x 2> /dev/null)
  if [ -z $mt ]
  then
    echo $x
  fi
done
```

in the file `no-mime-type.sh` (made executable etc etc).  Then

```
find . -type f \! -regex '.*\.svn.*' | xargs no-mime-type.sh
```

There's probably a better way to avoid the `.svn` directories that are lying around.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

Have a script like this:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 for x do
    mt=`svn propget svn:mime-type $x`
     if [ -z $mt ]; then
        echo "setting mime-type for $x"
        svn propset svn:mime-type MIME_TYPE_HERE $x
    fi
 done
```

Then you could call it via `xargs` and `find`

```
find . -type f -name "newfile*" -print | xargs my_check_script.sh
```

Comment: I'd probably want echo $x inside that if, but yeah, that seems reasonable.